# Python dataclasses.dataclass reference to variable instead of instance variable

Tags: python, instance-variables, class-variables

In the following code, the default values in the definition of the `Container` class should produce new instance variables for `c1.a` and `c2.a`.

Instead, it looks like `c1.a` and `c2.a` are referencing the same variable.

Is `@dataclass` creating a class variable? That does not seem to be consistent with the intended functionality, and I cannot find anything about class variables in the documentation.

So, I think this is a bug. Can someone explain to me how to fix it? Should I report it as a bug on the python tracker?

I know this issue must be related to the way python passes objects by reference and built-in types by value since the `b` attribute *(which is just a float)* shows the expected/desired behavior while the `a` attribute *(which is a user-defined object)* is just a reference.

Thanks!

#### Code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class VS:
    v: float  # value
    s: float  # scale factor
    
    def scaled_value(self):
        return self.v*self.s

@dataclass
class Container:
    a: VS = VS(1, 1)
    b: float = 1

c1 = Container()
c2 = Container()

print(c1)
print(c2)

c1.a.v = -999
c1.b = -999

print(c1)
print(c2)
```

#### Ouputs:

```
Container(a=VS(v=1, s=1), b=1)
Container(a=VS(v=1, s=1), b=1)
Container(a=VS(v=-999, s=1), b=-999)
Container(a=VS(v=-999, s=1), b=1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the OP's original example, a single `VS` object is created when the `Container` class is defined. That object is then shared across all instances of the `Container` class. This is a problem because user-defined classes such as `VS` result in a mutable objects. Thus, changing `a` in any `Container` object will change `a` in all other `Container` objects

You want to generate a new VS object every time a `Container` class is instantiated at initialization time. To do this, using the `default_factory` of the `field` function is a good way to go about it. Passing a lambda function allows all this to be done inline.

I added a `c` member variable to container with another `VS` class to illustrate that the members are independent when done this way.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class VS:
    v: float  # value
    s: float  # scale factor
    
    def scaled_value(self):
        return self.v*self.s

# Use a zero-argument lambda function for default_factory argument of field function.      
@dataclass
class Container:
    a: VS = field(default_factory=lambda:VS(1,1))
    b: float = 1
    c: VS = field(default_factory=lambda:VS(1,2))

c1 = Container()
c2 = Container()

print(c1)
print(c2)

c1.a.v = -999
c1.c.s = -999

print(c1)
print(c2)
```

Output:

```
Container(a=VS(v=1, s=1), b=1, c=VS(v=1, s=2))
Container(a=VS(v=1, s=1), b=1, c=VS(v=1, s=2))
Container(a=VS(v=-999, s=1), b=1, c=VS(v=1, s=-999))
Container(a=VS(v=1, s=1), b=1, c=VS(v=1, s=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Thanks Eric S for providing an explanation:

> c1 and c2 share the same instance of a. This is the mutable default argument problem: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments
> Use a default_factory to create a new VS for each container.

The default_factory does not allow me to have a unique set of default VS values for multiple attributes since the VS defaults will need to be defined in the VS dataclass.  For example, if I wanted a to default to VS(1,1) but I wanted b to default to VS(1,2), the default_factory does not help me.  So, I found I workaround, which is to create a dict of keyword entries and pass a deepcopy into my Container() constructer (note, that if I do not pass a deep copy, I get the same issue as above).  Here is my final code snippet and the output:

#### Code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from copy import deepcopy

@dataclass
class VS:
    v: float = 1 # value
    s: float = 1 # scale factor
    
    def scaled_value(self):
        return self.v*self.s

@dataclass
class Container:
    a: VS = field(default_factory=VS)
    b: float = 1

ip = {'a':VS(2,1),'b':1}
c1 = Container(**deepcopy(ip))
c2 = Container(**deepcopy(ip))

print(c1)
print(c2)

c1.a.v = 0
c1.b = 0

print(c1)
print(c2)
```

#### Output:

```
Container(a=VS(v=2, s=1), b=1)
Container(a=VS(v=2, s=1), b=1)
Container(a=VS(v=0, s=1), b=0)
Container(a=VS(v=2, s=1), b=1)
```

Comment: See if my answer solves your problem. The mutable argument "feature" of python is probably my least favorite, even though I understand how it more-or-less simplifies the language's design.

Comment: Love this solution

Comment: Just to mention, if you like the solution I gave in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63818048/1361752, it is good practice to accept it as the "correct" answer. That helps people find it and gives me credit Stack Exchanges merit system. (I'm not too big on the credit, I've got more than I need, but it does mater to some, especially if they are starting out)

Comment: Thanks Caleb! I didn't know how to accept an answer before.  Just did it.